# CMAKE arguments for different ABI in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

I have to use different arguments parameters in Gradle for different ABIs, something like the following:

```
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^(aarch64)$")
                    arguments "-UV_LIBRARY=src/main/cpp/libuv/lib/libuv_armv8.a"
                else
                    arguments "-UV_LIBRARY=src/main/cpp/libuv/lib/libuv_armv7.a"
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Gradle will set `ANDROID_ABI` CMake variable ([link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#options)), so you can do this in `CMakeLists.txt` instead of `build.gradle`:

```
if(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
    target_link_libraries(target_name PUBLIC "src/main/cpp/libuv/lib/libuv_armv7.a")
elseif(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "arm64-v8a")
    target_link_libraries(target_name PUBLIC "src/main/cpp/libuv/lib/libuv_armv8.a")
endif()
```